# longtable inside tabbing

Tags: tables, longtable, tabbing

Is there a way to use `longtable` that can create table spanning multiple pages with `tabbing`? It seems using `tabular` inside `tabbing` works, like

```
\begin{tabbing}
xxxx\=xxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxx\=\kill
\>\begin{tabular*}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
foo & bar \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{tabbing}
```

but changing `\>\begin{tabular*}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}` to `\>\begin{longtable}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}` will lead to the error

> Missing \endgroup inserted.

Using `longtblr` from package `tabularray`, or using `tabularx` with package `ltablex` does not seem to work either.

Comment: No this is not possible and seems a weird thing to want?? Whatever alignments you would put in an outer tabbing could be part of the longtable. (I have used latex for over 30 years and don't think I have ever found need to use tabbing:-)

Comment: Thanks David! I am trying to use this template. http://yuba.stanford.edu/~sundaes/OLDAPPMATERIALS/2003FACULTYAPP/CV/

Comment: I would think the `OLDAPPMATERIALS` in that link would be a discouragement to use it. If you want to make a CV (Résume) there are newer LaTeX templates to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the file, and actually, in the code that is not commented out, the `tabbing` is only used to shift one of the tabulars a bit to the right. If you replace the only `\>` that is not commented out by `\hspace{2em}` you get approximately the same effect. You can then remove all the `\begin{tabbing}` and `\end{tabbing}` lines and the corresponding line following the `\begin{tabbing}` with the `\kill` command at the end.

The only difference will then be that the vertical spacing is a bit difference, as the `tabbing` environment adds some vertical space before and after. If that bothers you you can add some `\vspace` commands.

Once you have removed the `tabbing` environments you can use `longtable` instead of `tabular`.

But as I said in my comment, there are better CV slasses/styles available in LaTeX, for example `moderncv`, or if you want to be swamped with all the possibilities, see https://www.ctan.org/topic/cv

Comment: Thanks a lot Pieter for your answer and comment! When I change as you recommended by using `longtable`, I find I am not able to make the width the same as the file, say to `\linewidth`. I tried to search on this but seems there is no very simple solution. Do you have any idea on this? Also, `tabularx` does not seem to support changing the width. I will also try to check the packages you mentioned.

Comment: Using the method provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577082/large-longtable-to-fit-in-latex) and adding an extra empty column along with tuning the width of each column, I am able to produce the desired effect, although very tricky. Maybe there can be some more elegant solutions.

Comment: `\setlength\LTleft{0pt} \setlength\LTright{0pt} \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}...}` should make your longtable as wide as the text.

Comment: `\setlength\LTleft` and `\setlength\LTright` work well. Thanks a lot!